# Object property still undefined after not-empty check

Tags: reactjs

I have a state called data, which is defined like this:

```
  interface DataType { [key: string]: string; }
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<DataType>({});
```

Then I pull data from the server and set the data to state, like this:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:1202/data")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          setData(json);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Up to that point, everything works perfectly. Below, I check, wether data is still an empty object. I use this piece of code:

```
  const isEmptyObject = (data: {} | null) => {
    if (data !== null && typeof data === "object" && !Array.isArray(data)) {
      return Object.keys(data).length === 0;
    }
    return false;
  };
```

I tested it and as I tested it, it worked.

Now comes the problem. In the next piece of code, I check wether data still contains an empty object, using the `isEmptyObject`-function from above.

```
if (isEmptyObject(data)) {
    return (
      <div>loading...<div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <IonPage>
        <CustomHeader pageName={"Widgets"} pageColor={"success"} />
        <IonContent>
          <IonRow>
            <WidgetPickerCard
              widgetNr={1}
              widget={data.Widget1}
            />
          </IonRow>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );
  }
};
```

For some reason, once data does not contain `{}` anymore and the `else` part is returned, data.Widget1 is still `undefined`.
How is that possible?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show if you add that line right before `if (isEmptyObject(data))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data was `{ foo: 'bar' }` then the object would not be empty, but `data.Widget1` would still be `undefined` since that key does not exist.

So I suspect that `data` has keys and values, but just does not have a key named `Widget1` that you are expecting.

If you only want to proceed if `Widget1` exists, you may try something like:

```
if (isEmptyObject(data) && data.Widget1) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found out what the problem was! My JSON-Formatting was wrong.